# How to set streams flushed instantaneously beforehand

Tags: java, unit-testing, netbeans, stream, system.out

I'm writing a package for unit testing in `Netbeans IDE`. Now I'm printing flow of execution statements to `System.out` while error statements to `System.error`. Now, since they are two different streams they are printing out of order. I mean they are not printing synchronized. I know `flush` method makes the statements printed instantaneously but writing this after every such statement is tedious. How to configure beforehand streams to flush immediately. May be at the start of unit testing?.

I want this, because I want to take the advantage of two different colors that `Netbeans` shows for two streams' of output.

Also, any wrong points in my approach & suggestions for betterment are most welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be another possibility, so give it a try:

```
import java.io.FileDescriptor;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class SystemOut {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hi");

        final OutputStream newOs = new OutputStream() {
            FileOutputStream fdOut = new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out);

            @Override
            public void write(int b) throws IOException {
                this.fdOut.write(b);
            }
        };

        System.setOut(new PrintStream(newOs));
        System.out.println("Hi, again");
    }
}
```

The idea is to replace the existing buffered output stream with an unbuffered one.

Comment: this is better...so there is no method for stream to be configured as such? you could have combined the two answers in one by editing...

Comment: I am not aware of a means in Java to reduce the buffer size of an existing `BufferedWriter` after he has been constructed.

Comment: Each message will be sent to disk immediately. This will affect performance of tests even more than usual logging.

Comment: @Maksim I agree. Both answers I provided represent technical solutions. As for designing/writing tests, I have already added a comment in my other answer.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't print flow of execution by yourself. Where is a lot of reasons not to do it:

- You shouldn't print state of successfull tests. There is a very
  limited count of reasons to do that. What you are actually want from
  your tests is to find bugs, not the well done cases. Focus on your
  problem.
- All modern frameworks for unit testing, such as *jUnit* or *TestNG*,
  provides you built in mechanisms for test results output. Just spend
  some time to learn them and your tests will be much more informative.
- Redundant logging slows your tests, which is critical because they
  should be launched often.
- If you use [Fail fast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast) practice you will be interested only in one
  failing message at once. This is good approach which allows you focus
  more effective.

In short you will not read success logs because they are useless. For failing tests you have standart assertions with messaging.

Answer (score 1):

You could just wrap `println()` and `flush()` in another method:

```
void out(String s) {
  System.out.println(s);
  System.out.flush();
}
```

Anyway, looking at the way I write tests: There are only *info* messages. *error* messages are written implicitly by failed assertions.

Comment: +1 for that thought.....but is there any way in java api with out me doing this kind of stuff.